# LyX: show changes in output causes emergency stop

Tags: lyx, compiling, trackchanges

I have an article from my collaboration that I've been working on in LyX for days. I've been using track changes on it, and sometimes I've propagated those changes to the output pdf with no problems. Today I tried to compile the pdf without the tracked changes shown, and it compiles fine, just giving me BibTeX errors which are not new and have no effect on whether or not it compiles.

If instead I use "Show changes in output" it refuses to compile just giving me two emergency stop messages.

I realise that people will want a minimum working example, but I was hoping there might be a simple solution, like changing the way that it's compiled or something, before I spend a lot of time trying to isolate the problem.

Here's hoping!

Comment: If you really get errors (and not only warnings) from bibtex you should handle them. Even if the compilation continues after error the output can be arbitrary nonsense.  Apart from this: you are not giving enough information to help you.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! I can understand why you are hoping for a solution without an mwe. That makes sense! However, I do think that in this case a mwe is needed. Ideally you would post both a mwe .lyx file and a mwe .tex file. Hopefully you could make the mwe without the BiBTeX so that we could separate those two issues. If you do end up posting a mwe .lyx file please `@` me. No matter what you end up doing, best of luck!